# Validate password against previously hashed passwords using NetValidatePasswordPolicy

Tags: c#, active-directory

According to Microsoft documentation **NetValidatePasswordPolicy** has possibility to implement feature to check password history and avoid reuse of previous passwords. I have gone through all the examples of this API but non of them provide me with functional of how to check Password history. Can somebody guide me how to verify password history?

```
    public static NET_API_STATUS ValidatePassword(string password)
    {
        var outputArgs = new NET_VALIDATE_OUTPUT_ARG();
        var inputArgs = new NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_CHANGE_INPUT_ARG();
        var passwordHistory = new NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_HASH();

        IntPtr inputPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr outputPointer = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {

            inputArgs.PasswordMatched = true;
            inputArgs.ClearPassword = Marshal.StringToBSTR(password);
            //var serverName = System.Environment.MachineName;
            string userNameToCheck = @"usr";
            //inputArgs.ClearPassword = Marshal.StringToBSTR(password);
            inputArgs.UserAccountName = userNameToCheck;

            // If using a secure string
            ////inputArgs.ClearPassword = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(secureStringPassword);

            inputPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(inputArgs));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(inputArgs, inputPointer, false);

            NET_API_STATUS status = NetValidatePasswordPolicy("serverdc1", IntPtr.Zero, NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_TYPE.NetValidatePasswordChange, inputPointer, ref outputPointer);

            if (status == NET_API_STATUS.NERR_Success)
            {
                outputArgs = (NET_VALIDATE_OUTPUT_ARG)Marshal.PtrToStructure(outputPointer, typeof(NET_VALIDATE_OUTPUT_ARG));
                NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_HASH OutPasswordHistory = new NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_HASH();
                OutPasswordHistory.Hash = outputArgs.ChangedPersistedFields.PasswordHistory;
                OutPasswordHistory.Length = outputArgs.ChangedPersistedFields.PasswordHistoryLength;

                // Copy the Structure to the IntPtr

                if (outputArgs.ValidationStatus == NET_API_STATUS.NERR_Success)
                {
                    // Ok
                    string emtp;
                }

                return outputArgs.ValidationStatus;
            }
            else
            {
                return status;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can ask for a specific component of the policy to be tested - just the sum of the policy against the provided password.

Comment: It is ok for me if the whole policy is validated, but i am not getting the error about password history policy. I have attached code i am using.